# BGE Error: 'VideoTexture.Texture' object has no attribute 'materialID'

Tags: python, blender, attributeerror, videotexture

I tried to change the texture of an object in the blender game engine.
I thought it would be a good idea to use the Texture Replacement from the [Video Texture (bge.texture)](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_0/bge.texture.html). 
I tried to run the following script:

```
def createTexture(cont):
    obj = cont.owner

    # get the reference pointer (ID) of the internal texture
    ID = texture.materialID(obj, 'Kraftwerk2.png')

    # create a texture object
    object_texture = texture.Texture(obj, ID)

    # create a new source with an external image
    url = logic.expandPath(new_file)
    new_source = texture.ImageFFmpeg(url)

    # the texture has to be stored in a permanent Python object
    logic.texture = object_texture

    # update/replace the texture
    logic.texture.source = new_source
    logic.texture.refresh(False)

def removeTexture(cont):
    """Delete the Dynamic Texture, reversing back the final to its original state."""
    try:
        del logic.texture
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

but it failed with the following error message:

> Python script error - object 'Plane', controller 'Python': Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "F:\Benutzer\Merlin\MW-Industries\Blender
>   Dateien\Cinema\Render-Blend\MoonSpace.ble nd\Test.py", line 19, in
>   createTexture **AttributeError: 'VideoTexture.Texture' object has no
>   attribute 'materialID'**

Is there a way to solve the problem?

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer so I executed module "createTexture" from the Python Controller.

Comment: Are you importing texture from bge? and/or do you have another variable named texture that is interfering?

Comment: @sambler No I don't have another variable named texture. Already checked that out. However, I recreated the script new and it worked. I don't know what the problem was.